How Do I Make Requests To My Domain Hit My Endpoint?
I am currently running the domain catgenesim.com, and I have the frontend configured. The backend says that it is running, but whenever I try to hit anything on the backend, it just times out after a while.
I have added breakpoints in Visual Studio, but they never get hit, so clearly nothing is going through.
Here is my Program.cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using LettuceEncrypt;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Configure Kestrel and LettuceEncrypt
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(kestrel =>
{
    kestrel.ListenAnyIP(49155, portOptions =>
    {
        portOptions.UseHttps(h =>
        {
            h.UseLettuceEncrypt(kestrel.ApplicationServices);
        });
    });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddLettuceEncrypt();

// Add CORS policy
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        policy => policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader());
});

// Configure logging
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.AddDebug();
builder.Logging.AddEventSourceLogger();

builder.WebHost.UseSockets(socketOptions => {
    socketOptions.CreateBoundListenSocket = endpoint => {
        var ip = (IPEndPoint)endpoint;
        var listenSocket = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        if (ip.Address.Equals(IPAddress.IPv6Any))
        {
            listenSocket.DualMode = true;
        }
        listenSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        listenSocket.Bind(endpoint);
        return listenSocket;
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// Use CORS policy
app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UsePathBase("/api");

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


And my appsettings.json, with my email removed for my privacy
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://catgenesim.com:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://catgenesim.com:5001"
      }
    },
    "LettuceEncrypt": {
      // Set this to automatically accept the terms of service of your certificate authority.
      // If you don't set this in config, you will need to press "y" whenever the application starts
      "AcceptTermsOfService": true,

      // You must specify at least one domain name
      "DomainNames": [ "catgenesim.com" ],

      // You must specify an email address to register with the certificate authority
      "EmailAddress": "EMAIL"
    }
  }
}



This is what I see when I run the program.
EDIT: More info
The last image shows this being run on my local machine for testing purposes. Here is what it looks like what I run it on my Lightsail instance.

And my lightsail routing setup


Are you running this on an EC2 instance? If so, what is your routing setup like? (direct to EC2, through ALB, Cloudfront, etc.)
From the last image you attached, it looks like you're only running the backend on your local machine.

@ClaudeKirke I was running this on my local machine for testing purposes, I am actually trying to run it on a Lightsail instance, please see updated post.

Is your front-end some sort of JavaScript browser based thing? If so, what does the browser's network tab show for those requests?

@MarkB The frontend is an angular-bootstrap setup. As for what the behavior it, it just says "pending" for a while before saying it timed out. The exact same happens on postman. Feel free to try for yourself on the link provided, just click the "generate" button and look in the network tab

I don't seem to be able to make any connection at all to :5000 or :5001.
This may be a problem with the OS's firewall. Ports 80 and 443 may be allowed by default since it's expected to be a web server, but ports like 5000 and 5001 are likely to be blocked.
With the only hint about the distro you're using being that bitnami shows up, I'll take a guess and assume that you're using CentOS - which is a common distro in lightsail templates.
CentOS usually has firewalld setup by default. Try allowing ports 5000 and 5001:

Log into SSH

List open ports
sudo firewall-cmd --list-ports


Open the port permanently by specifying the port number and protocol (TCP)
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5000/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5001/tcp


Reload Firewalld to apply changes:
sudo firewall-cmd --reload




I am using Ubuntu, but I found that Uncomplicated Firewall does something rather similar, so I installed it and opened those ports, see here: https://i.imgur.com/NUPZXdr.png
However, the situation seems the same.

Are you able to verify that the application is able to receive requests on ipv4? e.g. by doing curl 127.0.0.1:5000 on the server

Yes, when I do curl 129.0.0.1:5000 I receive no reply and when I do curl 129.0.0.1:5001 I get empty reply from server
